# Stripe Connect Express account refreshURL and returnURL are undefined

Tags: stripe-payments

I'm using Stripe Connect Express (new to it, following this [STRIPE API DOCS](https://stripe.com/docs/connect/collect-then-transfer-guide#create-an-express-account-and-prefill-information)). I am currently trying to create the AccountLink after successfully creating the Stripe Express Account.

However, I am not able to create the AccountLink as I'm getting an error when creating the AccountLink since the `account.refresh_url` and `account.return_url` appear to be `undefined`

```js
exports.onCreateAuthUser = functions.auth.user().onCreate(async (user) => {
  // Set your secret key. Remember to switch to your live secret key in production.
  // See your keys here: https://dashboard.stripe.com/account/apikeys
  const strip = require('stripe')('sk_test_key_input_here');

  const account = await strip.accounts.create({
    type: 'express',
  });

  let refURL = account.refresh_url;
  let retURL = account.return_url;

  console.log(
    'account log stuff -->',
    account,
    retURL,
    refURL,
    account.uid,
    account.userId,
    account.userRef,
    account.user,
    account.id,
    account.ref,
    account.pushId,
    account.customer_id,
  );

  const accountLinks = await stripe.accountLinks.create({
    account: account.id,
    refresh_url: refURL,
    return_url: retURL,
    type: 'account_onboarding',
  });
});
```

The `console.log` prints:

```
account log stuff --> undefined undefined undefined undefined undefined acct_1IbJSgPMwPhmaSsD undefined undefined undefined
```

Does anyone know why these attributes are undefined... and how I may fix it or what's wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The return and refresh URLs aren't URLs generated by Stripe, they are URLs you provide *to* Stripe so they can redirect your users to your website.

The `return_url` is where Stripe will redirect your user when they've finished the onboarding flow.

As for the `refresh_url`:

> The URL the user will be redirected to if the account link is expired, has been previously-visited, or is otherwise invalid. The URL you specify should attempt to generate a new account link with the same parameters used to create the original account link, then redirect the user to the new account link’s URL so they can continue with Connect Onboarding. If a new account link cannot be generated or the redirect fails you should display a useful error to the user.

https://stripe.com/docs/api/account_links/create#create_account_link-refresh_url

Comment: where do i get the URL I provide to Stripe though?

Comment: That's up to you to implement/figure out. It should probably be a URL to a landing page on your website.

Comment: Heads up, being redirected to `return_url` does not guarantee that the user has completed the flow. It also takes them there if they click the "back" arrow. If you want to handle events properly, you should do that in a webhook https://stripe.com/docs/connect/webhooks